# Adding if/else statements to shape algorithm for beginner

Tags: python, if-statement, shapes

I'm trying to add if/else statements to a set of code that outputs a shape when the user specifies the shape with an input string and having difficulties. How would I add a simple If/else statement to my shapes code so that it only outputs a shape with the correct input string and when an incorrect input string is used it outputs an error message stating "Shape is not defined".

One of my shape codes is a simple square algorithm:

```
def square(size, chr):
    row = 1
    while row <= size:
        col = 1
        while col <= size:
            print chr, 
            col = col + 1
        print '' 
        row = row + 1
    print ''
```

Updated code:

```
print('Please specify a shape to draw. Type S for square, T for triangle, R for reverse triangle, D for diagonal, and A for angle')
shape = raw_input('Please specify a shape to draw:')
size = input('Please enter a size:')
chr = raw_input('Please enter a drawing character:')
print''

valid_shape_codes =('"S":square, "T":triangle, "R":reversetriangle, "D":diagonal, "A":angle')
if shape in valid_shape_codes:
    valid_shape_codes[shape](size, chr)
else:
     print 'Shape is not defined'
```

Comment: Do you have a list of valid inputs for the user to type? If so, you can create a conditional block starting with `if shape in valid_shape_codes:`, proceed normally in the main branch, and `print "Shape is not defined"` in the `else:` branch.

Comment: Yes I do have a variety of shapes. I added the following code but it outputs all the shapes as long as it's one of the inputs. How would I change it to make only one shape appear per correct input? valid_shape_codes =('S, T, R, D, A')
if shape in valid_shape_codes:
    square(size, chr)
    triangle(size, chr)
    diagonal(size, chr)
    reversetriangle (size, chr)
    angle(size, chr)
else:
     print 'Shape is not defined'

Comment: You have to create an association between each shape code and function. One way to do this is to create a dictionary that maps shape codes to functions: `valid_shape_codes = {"S":square, "T":triangle, "R":reversetriangle ... }`, and then use `if shape in valid_shape_codes: valid_shape_codes[shape](size, chr)`

Comment: I keep getting an error message: TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str

Comment: Could you please update your question with your full code?

Comment: I updated the code above.

Comment: @user2955471: That's not how you create a dict.  Do what Asad told you to do.

Comment: You seem to be using some sort of cross of a tuple and a dictionary. Please take a look at how dictionaries work [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm)

Comment: Okay, I see my error. I thought these (), were a valid substitute for these {}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print('Please specify a shape to draw. Type S for square')
shape = raw_input('Please specify a shape to draw:')
size = input('Please enter a size:')
chr = raw_input('Please enter a drawing character:')
valid_shape_codes ={"S":square, "T":triangle, "R":reversetriangle, "D":diagonal, "A":angle}

if shape in valid_shape_codes:
    valid_shape_codes[shape](size, chr)
else:
    print "Shape is not defined"
print''
```

Comment: "when an incorrect input string is used it outputs an error message stating `Shape is not defined`".

Comment: Thank you! It works perfectly. Do you happen to know how to add a loop into this code so that it keeps asking for input? I'm trying to add a 'While true:' loop.